# Can an Angular Component have different forms depending on the calling component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working on a PWA with Angular. The designers already gave me all of the needed files for the project. I've noticed that there's one screen that behaves like a component but on another "screen" it behaves like a Material design dialog. I don't have any real problem (because I just have to respect the design) but on a personal level, I was wondering if an Angular component can be an Angular Material Dialog component (just in some part of an application and not the whole app).

Thanks in advance for clearing my mind :D

Comment: Maybe you want to use dynamic component like [this](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader)

Comment: Yes, you can use any component as a Material Dialog. The only problem is that it won't have `@Input()` bindings when used as a dialog. It will get the data from an injected parameter in the constructor. You can still have inputs and just figure out how to toggle between the two modes.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!